# Node JSON output malforms, unable to set HTTP Header: Content-Length to fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, sails.js

### The problem

#### Context & intent

I'm using a Node backend to **(1)** request API data from the Feedly Cloud, **(2)**  output that data in JSON format and then  **(3)** retrieve it from within a JS frontend.

This question relates to phase **(2)** only.

#### Initial issue

Whilst trying to print the data for the front-end to retrieve, I noticed that Node cut off mid-stream, leaving malformed JSON.

#### Attempted solution

I tried setting response headers for Content-Length before writing the content of the response, to force it to print the whole thing. That worked, around twice. But then it started fussing:

#### Ongoing failure

Now the app crashes on function run, claiming that I'm setting HTTP headers *AFTER* writing the content, or outputting to page, when as far as I'm aware I am not.

### The code

```
    var http = require('http')
      , authCode = 'xyz';

    var FeedlyController = {
        api: function(req, res) {
            http.get({
                host : "cloud.feedly.com",
                path : "/v3/"+req.params.resource,
                headers: { Authorization: "OAuth "+authCode }
            }, function(response) {
                response.on('data', function(json){
                  res.writeHead(200, {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(json, 'utf8')
                  });
                  res.write(json, 'UTF-8');
                  res.end();
                });
            });
        }
    }

    module.exports = FeedlyController;
```

### The error

```
_http_outgoing.js:331
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:331:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/jan/Sites/proxenos/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:63:22)
    at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (/Users/jan/Sites/proxenos/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:80:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ServerResponse.res.writeHead (/Users/jan/Sites/proxenos/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:79:28)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/jan/Sites/proxenos/api/controllers/FeedlyController.js:12:19)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:159:16)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:132:22)
```

Comment: You are writing your headers in your `success` function?

Comment: The `data` event might be firing multiple times as more data arrives.

Comment: @jasonscript Actually in later attempts it's written outside that, but I've not had success with either solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your data event is firing multiple times (because that's how it works, multiple `data` events and then one final `end` event.)

You might want to read through the readable stream documentation (that's what the `response` object is)
http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

I'd try changing your handler to look something like:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(json, 'utf8')
});

response.on('data', function(json){
  res.write(json, 'UTF-8');
});
response.on('end', function(){
  res.end();
});
```

Although you might be able to just pipe it through:

```
response.pipe(res);
```

(Instead of explicitly listening to the data and end events)

Comment: How would I get `Buffer.byteLength(json, 'utf8')` of undefined var `json`?

Comment: Never mind, I removed the content-length parameter and it's all worked out anyway. It must've been your conclusion that the data event did fire multiple times, that was interfering with output. Cheers!

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see that. Check the response headers and see if you can just reuse their content-length.